# Allow Rygel to talk to NetworkManager over DBUS?

Tags: networkmanager, d-bus, upnp

I'm trying to run [Rygel](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Rygel?action=show&redirect=Rygel), a UPNP media server, on a headless Fedora 20 system. I installed Rygel, and created a dedicated user and `systemd` unit for it. Rygel starts but it is not listening on the port I asked it to. I think this is because it fails to get a list of network interfaces from `NetworkManager`. How can I give it permission to talk to NetworkManager over DBUS?

**NOTE:** Both `NetworkManager` and `dbus-daemon` are confirmed running.

Output from starting Rygel:

```
Feb 02 19:13:08 inspiron systemd[1]: Starting Rygel DLNA server...
Feb 02 19:13:08 inspiron systemd[1]: Started Rygel DLNA server.
Feb 02 19:13:09 inspiron rygel[2276]: Rygel-Message: rygel-main.vala:87: Rygel v0.20.3 starting…
Feb 02 19:13:09 inspiron dbus-daemon[465]: dbus[465]: [system] Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.95" (uid=1001 pid=2276 comm="/usr/bin/rygel -c /etc/rygel.conf ") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="GetDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.12" (uid=0 pid=566 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Feb 02 19:13:09 inspiron dbus[465]: [system] Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.95" (uid=1001 pid=2276 comm="/usr/bin/rygel -c /etc/rygel.conf ") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="GetDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.12" (uid=0 pid=566 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Feb 02 19:13:09 inspiron rygel[2276]: ** (rygel:2276): WARNING **: Error fetching list of devices: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 3 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.95" (uid=1001 pid=2276 comm="/usr/bin/rygel -c /etc/rygel.conf ") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="GetDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.12" (uid=0 pid=566 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon ")
Feb 02 19:13:09 inspiron rygel[2276]: Rygel-Message: New plugin 'MediaExport' available
```

My Rygel `systemd` configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rygel DLNA server
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=rygel
Group=rygel
ExecStart=/usr/bin/rygel -c /etc/rygel.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

My (slightly redacted) rygel configuration:

```
[general]
upnp-enabled=true
video-upload-folder=@VIDEOS@
music-upload-folder=@MUSIC@
picture-upload-folder=@PICTURES@
media-engine=librygel-media-engine-gst.so
interface=192.0.2.100
port=49152
log-level=*:5
allow-upload=false
allow-deletion=false

[GstMediaEngine]
transcoders=mp3;lpcm;mp2ts;wmv;aac;avc

[Renderer]
image-timeout = 15

[MediaExport]
enabled=true
title=@REALNAME@'s media
uris=/path/to/media
extract-metadata=true
monitor-changes=true
virtual-folders=true

[Tracker]
enabled=false

[Playbin]
enabled=false

[ZDFMediathek]
enabled=false

[GstLaunch]
enabled=false

[Test]
enabled=false

[ExampleServerPluginVala]
enabled=false

[ExampleServerPluginC]
enabled=false

[ExampleRendererPluginVala]
enabled=false

[ExampleRendererPluginC]
enabled=false

[MPRIS]
enabled=false

[External]
enabled=fals
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the particular NetworkManager dbus methods used by Rygel require `at_console` authorization. [This](https://www.mail-archive.com/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg77723.html), apparently outdated, attribute predates polkit and is set via several pam modules during login and inherited by all child processes. Since systemd is unable to set this attribute and Rygel is started as a system (non-console) user, it is denied access to the requisite NetworkManager dbus methods.

The good news is that fedora [is coordinating](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1094121) the removal of the `at_console` dbus policy across various packages. The [policy file](https://www.mail-archive.com/devel@lists.fedoraproject.org/msg77736.html) provided in NetworkManager 0.9.9.1 works perfectly with the setup you describe. If you can't update, replace `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf` (might depend on distro) with [upstream org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/tree/src/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.conf).

Answer (score 1):

I found this blog post which sounds like what you're looking for. It's titled: [Setting up rygel on your Fedora system](http://ankursinha.in/blog/2013/05/12/setting-up-rygel-on-your-fedora-system/).

**NOTE:** *The following is excerpted from that blog post*

1. Install packages

   ```
   $ sudo yum install rygel tumbler gupnp-av
   ```

   > Tumbler is a dbus thumbnailer. If you don’t install it, rygel gives an error saying a dbus thumbnailer isn’t available. It also gives an error saying it couldn’t find “/usr/share/gupnp-av/didl-lite-v2.xsd”, and the gupnp-av package provides this. I’ve got to look into both these and see if they should be required by rygel by default.
2. Copy config file

   ```
   $ cp /etc/rygel.conf ~/.config/rygel.conf
   ```

   > Modify the config file. For example, I enabled the tracker plugin since I’m on gnome3. An important change is to use a fixed port, so you always know which one needs to be opened in your firewall. I randomly picked 65530. You can pick any that isn’t already reserved.
3. Open the firewall ports (UDP:1900 & TCP:65530)

   ```
   $ sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=1900/udp
   $ sudo firewall-cmd --add-port=65530/tcp
   ```

   check results

   ```
   $ sudo firewall-cmd --list-ports
   1900/udp 65530/tcp
   ```

Comment: None of this addresses the error I experienced. I've already configured rygel and opened the firewall. My problem is that rygel is not listening on either port 1900 or 49152.

Comment: @sciurus - the issue with installing `tumbler` sounded relevant to your issue.